# Recommended two-way encryption gems for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, open-source, encryption

I'm in need of a two-way encryption solution for Ruby, such as Blowfish, Rijndael (AES) or other. The problem, however, is that I can't find an appropriate gem for it. I would like for the library to support several different encryption algorithms so I can compare the performance of each for optimal integration i my application. I would also like it to be open source.

I came across [Crypt](http://crypt.rubyforge.org/), but it doesn't install properly and doesn't look like it's been updated in a while. [EzCrypto](http://ezcrypto.rubyforge.org/) won't install, either. I also saw [ruby-aes](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-aes), but that only supports Rijndael.

After some GitHub searching, I found [Encryptor](http://github.com/shuber/encryptor), which seems to be something like what I'm looking for. However, I'd love to get some ideas about any gems/libraries I might have missed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend [Shuber's Encryptor](http://github.com/shuber/encryptor) - it wraps the OpenSSL library so you can use anything it supports.

Comment: This is probably what I'll end up choosing, yes; just want to see if there are any other alternatives out there first, though.

Comment: Tried, tested and works very well.

Answer (score 12):

Why look so far, if everything you asked for is already available in your standard Ruby installation: the [OpenSSL](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) module.

The [Cipher](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html) class provides encryption and decryption, have a look at

```
require 'openssl'
puts OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers
```

for a list of available algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

I came across [Gibberish](https://github.com/mdp/gibberish) today. I haven't tried it out yet though.

Answer (score 0):

[ClaimToken](https://github.com/NuffieProductions/ClaimToken) is something we developed to handle claims based authentication with encryption and signing of json data. You can include this into almost any implementation you like. Cookies, Header etc..