# Are there any 2 way crypt library available for Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security, hash

I want something that will use a secret key to generate the hash. Also the hash generated should be URL safe and form safe.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997786/recommended-two-way-encryption-gems-for-ruby

Answer (score 0):

There is something already available in your standard Ruby installation: the [OpenSSL](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) module.

What you are talking about is probably an `OpenSSL::HMAC` that provides you with an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), a form of a secret key-based hash.

The result will be a simple Ruby string that potentially carries non URL-safe characters, you have to take care of making this URL-safe yourself. You could use either [URI.escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html) or simply hexencode the string using `str.unpack('H*')[0]` (see [String#unpack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/String.html#method-i-unpack)).